# smartest way to join two lists into a formatted string

Tags: python, list, join, format

Lets say I have two lists of same length:

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
```

and I want to produce the following string:

```
c = 'a1=b1, a2=b2, a3=b3'
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I have following implementations:

```
import timeit

a = [str(f) for f in range(500)]
b = [str(f) for f in range(500)]

def func1():
    return ', '.join([aa+'='+bb for aa in a for bb in b if a.index(aa) == b.index(bb)])

def func2():
    list = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        list.append('%s=%s' % (a[i], b[i]))
    return ', '.join(list)

t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import func1', stmt='func1()')
print 'func1 = ' + t.timeit(10) 

t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import func2', stmt='func2()')
print 'func2 = ' + t.timeit(10)
```

and the output is:

```
func1 = 32.4704790115
func2 = 0.00529003143311
```

Do you have some trade-off?

Comment: +1 I found no reason for the -1 (also literally).

Comment: @Jib Hello. New solution in my answer, see it please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

pat = '%s=%%s, %s=%%s, %s=%%s'

print pat % tuple(a) % tuple(b)
```

gives `a1=b1, a2=b2, a3=b3`

.

Then:

```
from timeit import Timer
from itertools import izip

n = 300

a = [str(f) for f in range(n)]
b = [str(f) for f in range(n)]

def func1():
    return ', '.join([aa+'='+bb for aa in a for bb in b if a.index(aa) == b.index(bb)])

def func2():
    list = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        list.append('%s=%s' % (a[i], b[i]))
    return ', '.join(list)

def func3():
    return ', '.join('%s=%s' % t for t in zip(a, b))

def func4():
    return ', '.join('%s=%s' % t for t in izip(a, b))

def func5():
    pat = n * '%s=%%s, '
    return pat % tuple(a) % tuple(b)

d = dict(zip((1,2,3,4,5),('heavy','append','zip','izip','% formatting')))
for i in xrange(1,6):
    t = Timer(setup='from __main__ import func%d'%i, stmt='func%d()'%i)
    print 'func%d = %s  %s' % (i,t.timeit(10),d[i])
```

result

```
func1 = 16.2272833558  heavy
func2 = 0.00410247671143  append
func3 = 0.00349569568199  zip
func4 = 0.00301686387516  izip
func5 = 0.00157338432678  % formatting
```

Comment: Notice that in this case the string formatting pattern must match the number of elements in your lists. If this number is a constant you can still generate the pattern once and for all and apply the formatting several times.

If you want to avoid the extra "," at the end :
`pat = ", ".join(n * ("%s=%%s",))`

Answer (score 33):

This implementation is, on my system, faster than either of your two functions and still more compact.

```
c = ', '.join('%s=%s' % t for t in zip(a, b))
```

Thanks to @JBernardo for the suggested improvement.

In more recent syntax, `str.format` is more appropriate:

```
c = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*t) for t in zip(a, b))
```

This produces the largely the same output, though it can accept any object with a `__str__` method, so two lists of integers could still work here.

Answer (score 8):

Those two solutions do *very* different things. The first loops in a *nested* way, then computes indexes with `list.index`, effectively making this a doubly-nested for loop and requiring what you could think of as 125,000,000 operations. The second iterates in lockstep, making 500 pairs without doing 250000 operations. No wonder they're so different!

Are you familiar with [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for describing the complexity of algorithms? If so, the first solution is *cubic* and the second solution is *linear*. The cost of choosing the first one over the second one is going to grow at an alarming rate as `a` and `b` get longer, so no one would use an algorithm like that.

---

Personally, I would almost certainly use code like

```
', '.join('%s=%s' % pair for pair in itertools.izip(a, b))
```

or if I wasn't too worried about the size of `a` and `b` and just writing quick, I would use `zip` instead of `itertools.izip`. This code has several advantages

- It's linear. Although premature optimization is a *huge* problem, it's best not to cavalierly use an algorithm with an unnecessarily bad asymptotic performance.
- It's simple and idiomatic. I see other people write code like this frequently.
- It's memory efficient. By using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (and `itertools.izip` rather than `zip`), I don't build unnecessary lists in memory and turn what could be an O(n) (linear)-memory operation into an O(1) (constant)-memory operation.

---

As for *timing* to find the fastest solution, this would almost certainly be an example of premature optimization. To write performant programs, we use theory and experience to write high-quality, maintainable, good code. Experience shows it's at best futile and at worst counterproductive to stop at random operations and ask the question, "What is the best way to do this particular operation," and trying to determine it from guessing or even testing.

In reality, the programs with the best performance are the ones that are written with code of the highest quality and very selective optimizations. High-quality code that values readability and simplicity over microbenchmarks ends up being easier to test, less buggy, and nicer to refactor--these factors are *key* for effectively optimizing your program. The time you spend fixing unnecessary bugs, understanding complicated code, and fighting with re factoring can be spent optimizing instead.

When it comes time to optimize a program -- after it's tested and probably documented -- this is not done on random snippets, but on ones determined by actual usecases and/or performance tests, with measurements collected by [profiling](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html). If a particular piece of code is only taking 0.1% of the time in the program, no amount of speeding up that piece is going to do any real good.

Comment: Agree with that. Like you said, they do very different things but the result is the same. Just wondering if you could do better than func2 in a cleaner way...

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ', '.join(i + '=' + j for i,j in zip(a,b))
'a1=b1, a2=b2, a3=b3'
```

Comment: or `itertools.izip(a,b)` if the lists are pretty long and you don't want to create another long list in memory.